# cypress e2e sample todo.cy.js test failing in a specific scenario

Tags: cypress

In the provided [todo.cy.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/cypress/e2e/1-getting-started/todo.cy.js#L67) test script, the 'can check off an item as completed' test fails when you try and choose 'Walk the dog' instead of 'Pay electric bill'.

I believe this might probably be exposing a bug in cypress where when there is a click event on an nth checkbox, it gets applied to the first checkbox on the same list.

```
cy.contains('Walk the dog')
      .parent()
      .find('input[type=checkbox]')
      .check()

cy.contains('Walk the dog')
      .parents('li')
      .should('have.class', 'completed')
```

Comment: No, it passes. Did you forget to change the text in both `cy.contains()`?

Comment: Thanks for the response - I replaced both (edited my post with the code as well this time).  for what its worth I am on an M1 mac - not sure if that has anything to do with it.